# How to translate with Qt Linguist with label arguments (%1)

Tags: qt, arguments, translation, qlabel

I got a line for a Qlabel like this:

```
QString(tr("Are you sure you want to delete the scene called %1 ?")).arg(variable);
```

Some people told me you can't translate that.  They told me to append different strings with the parameters and the text...

But what about a phrase using various parameters? How does the translator know which order if it is appended in that order?.

Has no sense for me. There must be a way!.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should should drop the QString(...) part, since tr() already returns a QString. Otherwise I don't see a problem with the translation of the following code:

```
tr("Are you sure you want to delete the scene called %1 ?").arg(variable);
```

In the [Use QString::arg() for Dynamic Text](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/internationalization.html#use-qstring-arg-for-dynamic-text) part of the Qt documentation you can find more information.

Comment: Superb. That´s what i wanted. Exactly.

Comment: How to use this in a QLabel on statusBar()?